# insert special characters between a field in a row

Tags: text-processing

I have rows in a file which each one has 20 fields.
At the 15th column of each row I need to do some insertions of 
special characters

```
x;x;x;x;x;x;x;x;x;x;x;x;x;YYYYY;x;x;x;x;x;x
x;x;x;x;x;x;x;x;x;x;x;x;x;YYYYY;x;x;x;x;x;x
```

could become

```
x;x;x;x;x;x;x;x;x;x;x;x;x;||YYYYY||;x;x;x;x;x;x
x;x;x;x;x;x;x;x;x;x;x;x;x;||YYYYY||;x;x;x;x;x;x
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to put "||" at the 15th collumn, you could do something like this:

```
awk -F ";" '{OFS=";"; $15="||" $15 "||"; print}' inputfile.txt
```